# lua attempt to call global 'Person' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

why do i get this error?
this is my code, and I'm trying to "dofile" from somewhere else but i know this code has the bug.

```
Person{ Name = "Jack", Age = 33, Occupation = "programmer"}
Person{ Name = "Rob", Age = 43, Occupation = "Dude"}
```

the other page code is:

```
function Person(p)
  print(p.Name, p.Age, p.Occupation)
end

dofile(People.lua)
```

Comment: You haven't posted enough code to determine an issue. Do you have `Person` defined elsewhere? The error is stating that it can't find anything named `Person` in the local/global scope.

Comment: It should be `dofile("People.lua")` but that does not explain the error message.

Comment: that was it but i guess you can't run the first part by itself